# How to implement mathLive library for math input in a React Native application?

Tags: react-native, mathjax, mat

I'm working on a React Native application that aims to help students improve their math skills. The application needs to display math equations and requires users to enter math-related answers.

To display math equations, I'm currently using the mathJax library. However, I'm having trouble finding a way to input math-related answers because my native keyboard is not advanced enough for this task (can not use advanced symbols like this √ ∫ µ ƒ ).

After researching, I found the mathlive ([mathlive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathlive)) library, which seems to support my requirements. However, I'm unable to implement it in my React Native application as it is not supported.

Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround for this issue? I would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to integrate mathlive with my React Native application or any alternative libraries that I can use to input math-related answers.

Thank you in advance.